# How to disable gesture recognizer in navigationBar?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

I have a question about disabling gesture recognizer in nationBar
Now, I'm developing an E-book application for iPad. I used `UIGestureRecognizer` to implement the effect of turning pages. but I coincidently found that if I swiped in the navigation bar at the top of screen, it also worked. So, how can I disable the gesture recognizer in navigation bar and just enable it for the rest of screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an outlet to your navigation bar, you should be able to handle this in your gesture handling method

```
- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([myNavBar frame], [gesture locationInView:self.view])) {
        // gesture occured in your navigation bar, so return;
        return;
    }
    // continue with your normal code for handling the gesture;
}
```

That should do the trick for you